# What is this cryptic artifact name created by the Publish Symbols Azure DevOps task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image]

The Publish Symbols task looks like this:

```
- task: PublishSymbols@2
      displayName: Publish Symbols
      timeoutInMinutes: 5
      inputs:
        SymbolServerType: FileShare
        SymbolsPath: '\\devstatic\symbols\xyz'
        TreatNotIndexedAsWarning: true
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['PublishSymbols'], true))
```

It is as if it expects a BuildConfiguration variable. But I do not have it. Do I need to declare it? Am I doing something wrong? Do I lose anything by not having it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is as if it expects a BuildConfiguration variable. But I do not have it. Do I need to declare it? Am I doing something wrong? Do I lose anything by not having it?

This behavior is by expected. You did nothing wrong.

When we use the task [Index Sources & Publish Symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops) task, there is a argument **Artifact name**:

[image]

Which the default value is **Symbols_$(BuildConfiguration)**. If you provide the BuildConfiguration in the variable with value `release`, the name of the link to your published release symbols would be `Symbols_release`.

So, you just need provide the `BuildConfiguration` in the variable, if you do not want to do that, just modify the default value of `Artifact name`, like, `Symbols_Test`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do I need this artifact in the first place? What is it?

Comment: @mark, The document explained it as "Specify the pattern used for the name of the link from the artifact tab in the build summary to the file share where you are publishing your symbols.", then you can also check the source code: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/775dccd55d5f519f30becbb7a72e4305deca04f9/Tasks/PublishSymbolsV2/PublishSymbols.ps1#L158